# Need to populate value into a row using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

I have stored contact in one table and their relationship in one table and child details in another. I need to populate "child name" of each parent using their childid ?

```
 CREATE TABLE contact_table(
 contactid NUMBER(3)
,contactname VARCHAR2(30)
,contactage NUMBER(2)
);


CREATE TABLE contact_maritalstatus(
statusid NUMBER(3)
,contactid NUMBER(3)
,contactgender VARCHAR2(8)
,contactstatus VARCHAR2(10)
);
CREATE TABLE contact_relation(
relationid NUMBER(3)
,contactid NUMBER(3)
,partnerid NUMBER(3)
,childid NUMBER(3)
);
CREATE TABLE contact_child(
childid NUMBER(3)
,contactid NUMBER(3)
);

SELECT cb.contactname,cm.contactgender,cm.contactstatus,cr.childid
FROM contact_table cb 
 inner join contact_maritalstatus cm  on cb.contactid = cm.contactid
 inner join contact_relation cr on cb.contactid = cr.contactid;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think you need `contact_maritalstatus` table..?

Comment: No. i use that to show marital status of each person.

Comment: From a modelling perspective Gender is an attribute of Contact not of Marital status: children have genders but not (usually) marital status. So `contactgender` belongs on `contact_table`. Also, using the one table `contact_relation` to store two types of relationship is messy. If a couple has more than one child the marriage relation will be recorded multiple times. Unless you intend to enforce an arc across `partnerid` and `childid`. A clearer solution could be to model `is_partner_of` and `is_parent_of` as two separate tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided the foreign keys so we have to infer your data model. However it seems parents and children are both in `contact_table`, and the `contact_relation` joins spouses to each other and parents to children. If so, you simply need join to `contact_table` a second time, using table and column aliases to distinguish the two instances:

```
SELECT cp.contactname as parent_name 
       , cm.contactgender
       , cm.contactstatus
       , cr.childid
       , cc.contactname as child_name 
FROM contact_table cp
 inner join contact_maritalstatus cm  on cp.contactid = cm.contactid
 inner join contact_relation cr on cb.contactid = cr.contactid
 inner join contact_table cc on cc.contactid = cr.childid
```